# Running Android Benchmarks

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to perform benchmark on a new developed Android app.
I need to figure out a way to simulate as many devices as possible, so, running the test on real devices is not feasible.
However, the Android emulator is very slow which makes it almost impossible to run more than a few on a single machine.

1. Is there emulator out there that might be faster than the one comes with the SDK (even in the price of less features).
2. Will the emulator run faster on Linux?
3. Any other idea for a possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I can think of a few reasons why you might want to test with "as many devices as possible" but I agree, your machine will limit the number of emulators.  If you explain what you're trying to test, someone might have a different solution that doesn't require very many emulators.

Comment: The app to test is an application which is a client app of a multiple servers environment. The app has to login on its startup and transmit images/location during its life time. The purpose of the benchmarks is to simulate as much clients as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to choose between finding a super fast emulator or writing a non android-app simulator.
I found that [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) is a good-enough for my needs.
I'm using VirtualBox with multiple virtual machines, each running the Android X86 which is an Android OS port to x86 processors.
It is much faster than the Windows emulator and it much more continent to use since it starts quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer BlueStacks for speed (particularly graphics) but also use Eclipse/Android SDK emulators for a range of phone and tablet sizes, for my benchmarks (free);

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm

Following show fast tablet, Eclipse emulator and BlueStacks speeds. Above also has results including Android X86 for number crunching benchmarks.

```
 *****************************************************
 T11 Samsung EXYNOS 5250 Dual 2.0 GHz Cortex-A15, Android 4.2.2
             Mali-T604 Quad Core GPU

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 09-Aug-2013 09.42

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+      39.13    41.52    32.19    27.25
  18000+      22.03    20.73    19.69    16.30
  36000+      12.24    12.23    10.75     8.68

 *****************************************************
 ET1 Eclipse Device ARM Emulator 2.4 GHz Core 2 

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 06-Mar-2013 21.17

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+       2.66     3.97     3.29     1.61
  18000+       1.48     1.84     1.72     0.88
  36000+       0.82     0.95     0.87     0.46

 *****************************************************
     BS1 BlueStacks Emulator on 3 GHz Phenom

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 06-Mar-2013 21.25

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+      41.72    42.02    32.90    20.72
  18000+      22.11    22.09    19.28    11.58
  36000+      11.16    11.14    10.35     5.89
```